# Reload site resources without reloading site

Tags: windows, firefox, web

is there a way of reloading the js/css files without having to `F5` or `CTRL + F5`? It's annoying having to reload the page each time I make a small change in these files.

(Using Firefox on Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS can be edited in the development console (F12) sadly if the JS is a separate script file then a refresh is the only way unless you paste the functions into the console too. This way it overwrites the functions already there.

Comment: ah ok no worries then, thanks :) before I give up all hope, do you know if there's an extension? Can't be that hard to code - it's just requeries the server for that url and replacing.. maybe.. maybe I'll make the extension xD thanks again

Comment: You're probably best to look through Firefox's site - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/collections/sacud/best_web_developer_tools/